# position: fixed doesn't occupy space, how to add it underneath?

Tags: css

I have this website, [mandelli.it][1], and I need to make the header sticky. I used the `position: fixed` on the header (`#masthead`) and it works fine. If you scroll down the page the header the navigation bar stays on top.
The problem is the space below, in fact, the title and some margin of the revolution slider item are hidden by the header itself because, apparently, `position: fixed` doesn't give the element a proper "space" on the document, so it can distantiate from the other elements.

I gave more margin to the elements below and it's working, but I should do it for every page and it's cumbersome. Any best practice on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance

[image: Without position: fixed CSS property]
[image: with position: fixed]

Comment: add a padding-top to the body equal or greater than the height of the fixed element. is the height of the header fixed or it could change?

Comment: _“but I should do it for every page and it's cumbersome”_ - why, do your pages not have a common structure in that at least the following content is wrapped in `main` or some other container, so that this can be applied via one single rule in the stylesheet? Even if not, a padding-top on body should be able to achieve the same effect, and that should be easy enough to apply to all pages via one rule.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan it worked out. No the height of it it's fixed, and on mobile it's a complete different behaviour. The solution worked fine!

Comment: @CBroe you are right, the #main container is always there. I will give the style Fabrizio mentioned to it

Comment: are you sure? I've just checked the site and for some viewports the main menu spans over two lines

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan yeah that shouldn't happen...so should I give the padding top equal to the biggest version of the header possible (the one 2 lines)?

Comment: this is a possible solution but it creates unnecessary space in most of the wide viewport, so you could 1) keep the menu always in one line, or 2) have a fixed-height header with a vertically centered menu or 3) have a JS listener on window resize, get the height of the header and use dinamically that value as the padding.

Comment: `position:sticky` does not have that effect that the following content disappears under the element, because that behaves like `relative`until the actual sticky-ness starts - so that could be an alternative, to handle a dynamic header height.